# input type name as $key value in php

Tags: php, html

```
echo form_dropdown("e_learning[$key][]",
                   $yes_no_array,
                   '',
                   'id="e_learning" 
                   class="form-control select2me"');
```

I want to do same thing for

```
<input type="number" 
       min="1" name="no_of_appointment[]" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="No of Appointment">
```

like this

```
<input type="number" 
       min="1" 
       name="no_of_appointment[$key][]" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="No of Appointment">
```

but this is not proper I am getting error Disallowed Key Characters.

I want to do this so can know which array he select according to `$key` value.

Comment: If you want to pass PHP processed values to HTML, you have to initiate and end the PHP interpreter with the tag `<?php ?>`, and choose some output method. Like: `<input type="number" min="1" name="no_of_appointment[<?php echo $key; ?>][]"  class="form-control" placeholder="No of Appointment">`

Comment: Consider posting the content of your `form_dropdown` function so we can know better what's going on inside your code.

Comment: thanks a lot. How can i miss that.  @AedixRhinedale

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass PHP processed values to HTML, you have to initiate and end the PHP interpreter with the tag `<?php ?>`, and choose some output method.

Like:

```
<input type="number" min="1" name="no_of_appointment[<?php echo $key; ?>][]"
      class="form-control" placeholder="No of Appointment">
```